# Número perfecto

Tags: c++

Tengo este código y quería que este modulo numeroPerfecto no fuera un modulo pero si parte del main, he intentado pero no fue capaz.

Intenté usar cambiando variables pero me salia todos los numeros, ahí hay que salir al final los números perfectos hasta llegar al número inserido por teclado. Ej: 500 no es perfecto, pero hay 6,28,496 hasta llegar a el.

```
int main()
{
    int numero, count = 0;
    char resp;
    cout<<"Desea ejecutar el programa? s/S, n/N"<<endl;
    cin>>resp;
    while(resp=='S' || resp== 's')
    {


        clrscr();
        cout<<"Introduzca un numero entero y le diremos si es perfecto o no."<<endl;
        cout<<"Numero: ";
        cin>>numero;
        while(numero<0)
        {
            cout<<"Este numero es negativo, hay que ser positivo, introduzca de nuevo: "<<endl;
            cin>>numero;
        }
        for (int i=1; i<numero; i++)
        {
            if (numero%i==0)
                count +=i;
        }
        if (numero==count)
        {
            cout<<numero<< " es perfecto.";
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<numero<<" no es perfecto.";
        }
        cout<<endl<<"Los numeros perfectos que hay hasta este numero es el: "<<endl;
        for (int k = 1; k <= numero; k++)
        {
            if (numeroPerfecto( k ))
            {
                if( count == 0 )
                {
                    cout << k;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << ", " << k;
                }
                count++;
            }

        }
        cout<<endl<<"Desea ejecutar de nuevo el progra? s/S o n/N"<<endl;
        cin>>resp;
    }

    return 0;
}
bool numeroPerfecto( int numero )
{
    int suma=0;

    for (int i = 1; i < numero; i++)
    {
        if (numero % i == 0)
            suma = suma + i;
    }

    return suma == numero;
}
```

Comment: Tengo una curiosidad: a que le llamas número perfecto? Segun tu código ningún número ingresado va a ser perfecto porque todos los números menores a este siempre tendrán un residuo. Haces un for hasta que i<numero, por lo tanto, si número es 500  la I va a llegar a 499. Y del 1 al 499 no habrá un número que dividido entre 500 tenga un residuo de 0.

Comment: La intención era que fuera contando los números hasta llegar en mi número ingresado y imprimirlas en pantallas los números perfectos hasta llegar a el. Lo curioso es que si funciona, pero el reto seria hacer los mismo pero sin el modulo numperoPerfecto. Lo que hace con los otros números es como si fuera el mismo que hago al principio.

Comment: Perdon, lei mal tu código en el resudo.

Comment: No entiendo por qué quieres, o necesitas, incluir tu función numeroPerfecto dentro del main. Por mi parte te sugeriría lo contrario. Mientras más dividas tu código en pequeñas secciones funcionales mejor será entenderlo y mantenerlo.

Comment: Si, también veo mejor así, pero quería comprender mejor como sería el dentro del main. Si es raro quererlo así pero lo necesito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar una función lambda:

```
 int main() {

    auto numeroPerfecto = [](int  numero) { int suma = 0;
                                        for (int i = 1; i < numero; i++)
                                            if (numero % i == 0)    suma = suma + i;
                                        return suma;
                                    };
    int numero, count = 0;
    char resp;
    cout << "Desea ejecutar el programa? s/S, n/N" << endl;
    cin >> resp;
    while (resp == 'S' || resp == 's')
    {
        cout << "Introduzca un numero entero y le diremos si es perfecto o no." << endl;
        cout << "Numero: ";
        cin >> numero;
        while (numero < 0)
        {
            cout << "Este numero es negativo, hay que ser positivo, introduzca de nuevo: " << endl;
            cin >> numero;
        }

        if (numeroPerfecto(numero)==numero)
        {
            cout << numero << " es perfecto.";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << numero << " no es perfecto.";
        }
        cout << endl << "Los numeros perfectos que hay hasta este numero es el: " << endl;
        for (int k = 1; k <= numero; k++)
        {
            if (numeroPerfecto(k)==k)
            {
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    cout << k;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << ", " << k;
                }
                count++;
            }

        }
        cout << endl << "Desea ejecutar de nuevo el progra? s/S o n/N" << endl;
        cin >> resp;
    }
```

};

Comment: Gracias por dedicarse a este problema, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

> [Un número perfecto es un entero positivo que es igual a la suma de sus divisores propios positivos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_perfecto).

Tenemos dos problemas separados en esta cuestión:

1. Encontrar los divisores de un número.
2. Determinar si la suma de sus divisores equivale al número.

Para encontrar el divisor de un número, usa el operador [módulo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operaci%C3%B3n_m%C3%B3dulo), suma los números que al pasar por el módulo devuelvan cero:

```
bool es_perfecto(int valor)
{
    int acumulado = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i < valor; ++i)
        acumulado += ((valor % i) == 0 ? i : 0);

    return valor == acumulado;
}
```

El algoritmo es mejorable, no hace falta comprobar todos los números del 2 hasta el valor.

Comment: ¿Como lo haría dentro del main? Ya que al final necesito mostrar también los números perfectos que hay hasta llegar al número ingresado por teclado.

Comment: Para hacerlo dentro de `main` basta con poner la función `es_perfecto` en dicha función. Si quieres analizar los números hasta el introducido, usa un bucle.

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que quieres algo así, es necesario reiniciar `count`, cada vez que vuelvas a ingresar otro número, caso contrario las siguientes veces, incluso 6 o 28 te saldrán como no perfectos.

```
int main()
{
    int numero, count = 0;
    char resp;
    cout << "Desea ejecutar el programa? s/S, n/N" << endl;
    cin >> resp;
    while (resp == 'S' || resp == 's')
    {
        count = 0;
        clrscr();
        cout << "Introduzca un numero entero y le diremos si es perfecto o no." << endl;
        cout << "Numero: ";
        cin >> numero;
        while (numero < 0)
        {
            cout << "Este numero es negativo, hay que ser positivo, introduzca de nuevo: " << endl;
            cin >> numero;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < numero; i++)
        {
            if (numero%i == 0)
                count += i;
        }
        if (numero == count)
        {
            cout << numero << " es perfecto.";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << numero << " no es perfecto.";
        }
        cout << endl << "Los numeros perfectos que hay hasta este numero es el: " << endl;
        for (int k = 1; k <= numero; k++)
        {
            int suma = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i < k; i++)
            {
                if (k % i == 0)
                    suma += i;
            }

            if (k == suma)
            {
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    cout << k;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << ", " << k;
                }
                count++;
            }

        }
        cout << endl << "Desea ejecutar de nuevo el progra? s/S o n/N" << endl;
        cin >> resp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por dedicarse a este problema, saludos.